# CondaHTTPError while creating the environment in linux

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, http-error

I am using linux aarch64 architecture and I try to create an environment after installing the miniconda in the linux. But I got condahttp error. This is my first time installing miniconda in linux and create environment in linux.

May I know how can I solve this issue? Does it needs to create any profile.h in miniconda ?

```
(base) su@L2:~$ conda create --name env1 python=2.7

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pk                                                                             gs/main/linux-aarch64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64'
```